# Retrieve Firebase parent from .push

Tags: firebase

I have the following code that creates a randomly generated parent in Firebase and stores a name and text like so:

```
    ref.push({
        name : myName,
        text : myText
    });
```

Then to retrieve the data, I use the `.on("child_added")`.
However, I'm trying to retrieve firebase's randomly generated parents and set them as the id's of their respective elements. 
Here is what I came up with so far:

```
    ref.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      var obj = snapshot.val();
      var parent = ...;
      $(".message").append('<div id="'+ parent + '"></div>');
   });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems you're looking for the name/key of the parent. You can get that through the [`key` method of the DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/key.html):

```
ref.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  var obj = snapshot.val();
  var parent = snapshot.key();
  $(".message").append('<div id="'+ parent + '"></div>');
});
```

If you want to know the key in your other code snippet, you can get it from the [reference that `push` returns](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html):

```
var newRef = ref.push({
    name : myName,
    text : myText
});
console.log(newRef.key());
```

Comment: Watch out, from Firebase 3.x `key()` is replaced with `key`!

Comment: @MasterScrat thanks for your note about Firebase 3.x